# Match pattern conflict with two HTML sections in Spring Security config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security to work properly with both **application/json** responses as well as the usual page-based responses. I believe this means that I need two **html** sections in my xml config, one for each type. Here is my security-config.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Spring Security for JSP, HTML pages etc -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/ui/app.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    <csrf/>  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
</http>

<!-- Spring Security for application/json -->
<http entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/json/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</http>

<!-- Configures the authentication entry point that returns HTTP status code 401 -->
<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.my.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<!-- Configures in-memory implementation of the UserDetailsService implementation -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider >
        <user-service>
            <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

When I run this it throws an exception with the message

> A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns ...

It does this regardless of the order of the two **html** sections in the xml, but it does not throw the exception if I remove the section for handling application/json

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. The **html** section takes a **pattern=** property that defaults to **"/**"** so you need to provide a **pattern=** property for at least one of the **html** sections. I amended my security-config.xml as follows and it now works:

```
<!-- Spring Security for application/json -->
<http pattern="/json/**" entry-point-ref="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/json/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</http>

<!-- Configures the authentication entry point that returns HTTP status code 401 -->
<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.my.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

<!-- Spring Security for JSP, HTML pages etc -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    ...
</http>
```

I didn't provide a **pattern=** for the page type responses as this broke the login function, so I had to re-order the **html** sections as well.